# some problem with fade (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have a simple script with image loading, it doesn't work good.

Here it is [removed]

When we click on a link:

- `.block img` removed by fade effect.
- `.load` block is showed by fade
- `.block img` `src` attribute replaced by link's `href`.
- we wait until new image is loaded, then wait 2 more seconds - it is important part.
- then we remove `.load` and show `.block img` by fade

The problem is, when we click on many links, they begin to fadeIn/Out many times.

**How do I fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what you try to achieve removing the `.load()`.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/EvXJr/7/

Comment: it should fadeOut current image and then fadeIn new one. In your example new image fades two times. Can you fix it?

Comment: like your fix
@Happy since I was already working on this, here's my edits http://jsfiddle.net/EvXJr/10/

Answer (score 1):

jquery has a handy [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. Alternately you can set a "running" flag when the animation starts and ignore all clicks until it is cleared at the end of the sequence.